# SQL Server Stored Procedure to generate a Code based on firstname and lastname

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, procedures

I'm new to SQL Server stored procedures. I was wondering how to go about writing this stored procedure. The scenario is:

The procedure takes firstname and lastname as parameters, on basis of that it takes the first letter or firstname and first letter of lastname and appends a number to the end of it and returns this string. If the string already exists in the database it will increment the number and return the string.

Example 1:

```
firstname: abc    
lastname: def    
output: ad001
```

Example 2:

```
firstname: pqr    
lastname: mno    
output: pm001
```

Example 3:

```
firstname: aaa    
lastname: ddd
output: ad002
```

(in this case output is `ad002` instead of `001` since the value `ad001` already exists in the database which was created by example 1)

Any help with this problem would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Update**)
You can use this logic in your procedure :

```
Declare
   @firstname varchar(10)= 'aaa',    
   @lastname varchar(10)=  'ddd',
   @output varchar(20)

insert into name_table 
   select 
      @firstname, 
      @lastname,
      substring(@firstname,1,1)+
      substring(@lastname,1,1)
      +RIGHT('000'+cast(COALESCE(max(substring(output,3,4)),0)+1 as varchar) ,4)
   from 
      name_table 
   where 
      output like substring(@firstname, 1, 1) + substring(@lastname, 1, 1) + '%'


select * from name_table
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/050c2/2)

Comment: The part where the next number is generated has issues. What would happen if the last number turned out to be `0009`? Apparently, your code [would produce `00010` instead of `0010`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/050c2/1). And what if there is no record for a particular letter combination yet? In your query, MAX() would evaluate to NULL in that case, and [so would the result of the entire expression](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1445/1).